# How a molecule electron cloud interact with polarised light to show optical activity and why only asymetrical molecules only do so?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I want to know how exactly light electrical component or anything else interact with e- cloud

Comment: I think this begs the question what do you know about quantum mechanics or basics of spectroscopy.